# When dragging the graphical device the labels don't move with the plot in R?

Tags: r, plot

The following is a **plotting frame for 28 plots:**

```
par(mfcol = c(7, 4), mar = rep(.1, 4), oma = rep(7, 4))

invisible(lapply(1:28, plot, t = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n"))
```

To add labels to **y-axis** (`side = 2`) of the above plotting frame I do the following:

```
mid.y = seq(grconvertY(0 + (1 / 14), "nic"), grconvertY(1 - (1 / 14), "nic"), l = 7)

gap.y = sort(c(mid.y[-length(mid.y)] + diff(mid.y)[1L] / 2, grconvertY(0:1, "nic")))

l = c('1/10', '1/3', '1', '3', '10', '30', '100', '> 100000')
mtext(l, side = 2, at = gap.y, line = 22, cex = .9, font = 2, las = 1) # notice `line = 22
```

## Question

The label positions are perfect. But if I drag the graphical device to the right or left the labels don't move with the plot? How can I fix the labels to move with plot (***please see the following 2 pictures***)?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complex plotting case. Thus, for complete control use `text()` instead of `mtext()`. This way you don't need to rely on `line =` argument which causes the problem you describe in your question above.

**Solution based on your R code above:**

```
text(grconvertX(0, "nic"), gap.y, l, xpd = NA, adj = 1, cex = 1.3, font = 2)
```